# Is there any option in Drive SDK for debugging?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am having troubles with my PHP application which uses Drive SDK. I am trying to update a file, but all the time I receive `500 Internal Error` message when I try to update file's contents.

I am looking for some way to debug the application. What would be most helpful for me is possibility to view how the entire request along with all headers look like. Is there any way to check it, or are there any other options for debugging?

Thank you a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still didn't find any option for debugging- However, I found how I can view the requests done by the API client.

Open `google-api-php-client/io/Google_REST.php` file and find `static public function execute(Google_HttpRequest $req)` function.

There you will find this line:
`$httpRequest = Google_Client::$io->makeRequest($req);`

Right under it put the following code: `var_dump($httpRequest);`

During every request the client will do, you will get dump of it's request.

Answer (score 0):

This question is still relevant but the accepted answer is very old.  If you wish to view the HTTP requests and server responses in version three, the file you need to edit is /vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php.  Locate the doExecute function and add `print_r($request->getUri());` to the first line.  Add `print_r($response->getBody()->read(1024));` to the line just before the function returns to see the response body.